# Batch random line for a .txt file

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a batch file and I wanted to display a splash in the main screen. I wanted the batch file to pick a random line from a text file and ECHO it. The file name would be `splashes.txt`.
And in it would be like:

```
More addicting the lemons   
Apples.  
This is a splash  
Test
```

The batch file would pick a random quote based on its line.
Like if the patch file picked line 2 it would ECHO "Apples."

Note that I'm using Windows 8.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried breaking the problem down into smaller steps? For example - how do you know how many lines there are to choose from? Once you establish a reasonable set of sub-tasks, you should be able to search StackOverflow or the web at large to find how to do each one. If not, then you can at least show what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Comment: Have you made any effort to do this yourself? Or at least done some research by searching here? This is written now as *Here are my requirements. Write my code for me. B back l8r to get ur wrk. Thx.*, and we're not a code writing service.

Comment: I have done lots of research. I have found ways but they did not work like I wanted it to. Why else would I be here? I don't appreciate your tone. Perhaps I could show you the source code to my batch file to prove how much I do on my own?

Comment: Showing at least a sample of your attempt to solve the problem shows that you aren't trying to use SO as a free code-writing service. That doesn't mean a full log of your work over the past week, nor does it mean a random few lines from some unrelated batch - just a representative sample which should be easily available on your machine to cut-and-paste - or won't be if you haven't made an attempt.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with others that you should attempt this on your own, this is a relatively straight-forward script which should serve as a good working example for learning:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

REM Source file.
REM The first line on this file should be blank as it will never be selected.
REM Additionally, this file should have no empty lines on the end.
SET TextFile=text.txt

REM Determine the number of lines.
SET NumLines=0
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (`TYPE %TextFile%`) DO SET /A NumLines=!NumLines!+1

REM Pick a random line.
SET /A RandomLine=(%RANDOM% %% %NumLines) + 1

REM Prevent skipping all the lines.
IF "%RandomLine%"=="%NumLines%" SET RandomLine=1

REM Print the random line.
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* skip=%RandomLine% delims=" %%A IN (`TYPE %TextFile%`) DO (
    ECHO %%A
    REM We are done. Stop the script.
    GOTO Finish
)

:Finish
ENDLOCAL
```

---

So close - but not quite. `SKIP` will always be at least 1 (since `SKIP=0` is invalid) hence the first line in the file can never be selected.

This is a file I derived from the above with a few tickles. I've also changed the filename because of the way I work. I'm using `q27829742.txt` containing the lines posted.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions

REM Source file.
REM The first line on this file should be blank as it will never be selected.
REM Additionally, this file should have no empty lines on the end.
SET "TextFile=q27829742.txt"

REM Determine the number of lines.
FOR /f %%a IN ('type "%textfile%"^|find /c /v ""') DO SET /a numlines=%%a

REM Pick a random line.
SET /A RandomLine=(%RANDOM% %% %NumLines%)

REM Prevent skipping all the lines.
IF "%RandomLine%"=="0" (SET "RandomLine=") ELSE (SET "RandomLine=skip=%randomline%")

REM Print the random line.
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* %RandomLine% delims=" %%A IN (`TYPE %TextFile%`) DO (
    ECHO %%A
    REM We are done. Stop the script.
    GOTO Finish
)

:Finish
ENDLOCAL
```

The `find /v /c` method counts lines in the file (find files lines that don't match (/v) "" (so that means all lines) and count them (/c) - simply more efficient.

Pick-random-number : removing the `+ 1` produces a result `0..(numlines-1)` which is the *actual* number of lines to `skip`.

Problem there is that `skip=0` is invalid, so construct a string which is eother *empty* (for `0`) or "skip=..." (otherwise) - all ready to be included in the `for /f` command-options.

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray spaces at the end of a line are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".

Comment: It doesn't work. FOR gives me a 'type test.txt is not recognized as a internal or external command'

Comment: Have to disagree - the batch works in its original form. The type of quotes used (single, double or backtick) is important **but** can be modified "for your convenience" by some utilities (like `WORD`) which try to process text documents as WP documents. `Notepad` is barely adequate for the job - a text editor (I use **editplus**) is preferred. Please avoid typos by cutting and pasting, not retyping. Batch can be very sensitive to apparently-minor changes.

Comment: @Magoo - Good edit. I thought about having the `Skip` statement expanded dynamically about an hour after I posted the answer. My original solution to this was to put a note where you define the source file to say that the first line shouldn't contain anything (so the `+1` would ensure skip was never 0). Other than that I didn't have any problems running the script as originally posted. Your method for counting the lines is much better though.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of lines to be, let's say 25.
You could have a vector holding each line, and then compute a random index and print out the corresponding line with the following example.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET line[0]=Apples.
SET line[1]=This is a splash
SET line[2]=Test
SET line[3]=...
SET line[24]=many lines later...


SET /A index=%RANDOM% % 25
ECHO !line[index]!
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I didn't know about 'vectors'

Answer (score 0):

A practical application of Jason Falkner's (and Magoo's) answer would be to their script and place it into a .cmd file that would reside in System32 (say randomline.cmd). This will integrate it into the command line utility, making it easily re-usable via a simple call line, avoiding you to have rewrite those lines over and over and over again in all your scripts. For example:

**if you call the Magoo/Falkner script randomline.cmd and place it in System32**

**randomline.cmd**

> @ECHO OFF
>       SETLOCAL
>       SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions
>
> ```
> REM Source file.
> REM The first line on this file should be blank as it will never be selected.
> REM Additionally, this file should have no empty lines on the end.
> SET "TextFile=%1"
>
> REM Determine the number of lines.
> FOR /f %%a IN ('type "%textfile%"^|find /c /v ""') DO SET /a numlines=%%a
>
> REM Pick a random line.
> SET /A RandomLine=(%RANDOM% %% %NumLines%)
>
> REM Prevent skipping all the lines.
> IF "%RandomLine%"=="0" (SET "RandomLine=") ELSE (SET "RandomLine=skip=%randomline%")
>
> REM Print the random line.
> FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* %RandomLine% delims=" %%A IN (`TYPE %TextFile%`) DO (
>     ECHO %%A
>     REM We are done. Stop the script.
>     GOTO Finish
> )
>
> :Finish
> ENDLOCAL
> ```

**you'll be able to use it anypoint in the command prompt by entering**

> ```
> randomline any_old_text_file.txt
> ```

**or if you want to use it in a cmd/bat script**

> ```
> call randomline any_old_text_file.txt
> ```

**And if you want to set a value for a variable in your script from a random line in a file, you can do:**

> ```
> call radomline file_containing_values_on_each_line.txt>%temp%\randomlinevalue.txt
> set /p any_old_variable=<%temp%\randomlinevalue.txt
> del %temp%\randomlinevalue.txt
> ```